# Android emulator starts but doesn't launch app

Tags: android-emulator

I created an AVD that starts but it doesn't run my app. The thing is that this application works on my friend's computer. It get's a time out on mine.I just want to make it work. I have doubled the adb connection time out to 10000. Here are my settings:

[image]

Can you find anything wrong or do u have any good advices? I'm using windows 7 by the way.

Comment: Do you see your app in the apps inside the emulator?

Comment: No, the emulator is only loading. I don't see anything. The only thing that's written on the emulator's screen is android.